# Excel formula based on background color

Tags: excel, function, colors, count

I want to count how many cells in a column are of a certain (background) color. How would I create a function that will do this for me?

I was thinking =SUM(IF(A:A == "#FFFFFF",1,0)) where #FFFFFF is the background color and we are looking in all of column A

Comment: use vba not formula. this is simple

Comment: I ended up using https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2815384

Comment: Sure. It says I can accept my own answer tomorrow.

Comment: What's the function to get the background color?

Comment: @skan See my answer [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24459417/2893712)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2815384

It is very simple and does not require knowledge of exactly what color the cell is. You can just select the cell and it is able to read the color automatically.

Comment: Unfortunatelly we need to create VBA code, there is no direct formula to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Filter the column by colour and use:

```
=SUBTOTAL(103,A:A)
```

but beware of the header.